# Automatically install new position when installing new module

Tags: joomla

If i want to add a new position to a template i have to do it manually in templateDetails.xml file. I am making a module and when installing it, i want it to automatically install new position, is it possible?

Comment: You have to amke changes on both templateDetails.xml and template's index.php or another part. Besides, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Im making a module that will basically work like some jquery image slider, when i write an article i can just write something like {loadposition custom_position} and it will load the whole module into the article.

Comment: To achieve that, you don't have to edit your template at all (and actually adding the position to the template would not be helpful). Joomla allows you to type anything in the module position, whether it is defined in your template or not. You would need to do this: http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_simple_module/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file and then add a query that runs in postflight to insert a record into the #__modules table to add an instance of the module in the position.

Comment: Actually it doesn't make any sense. You cannot predict what templates user is using, and if you and only adding module position in xml file won't add it to template index.php file itself.
If you're gonna use module for yourself, you can type anything into position field, but if you're gonna put extension into JED, adding custom position is useless.

Comment: Use a content plugin for that use case.